# How can we hide the Gutenberg editor Wordpress 5

Tags: wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using the Wordpress 5 for my site and I want to hide the `Gutenberg` editor and want to use the `classic editor` for the page and post creation. how can I hide the `Gutenberg editor`?

So far I have tried the following code to do this

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_true');
```

And this to hide the Gutenberg editor but none of them work.

```
 // disable for posts
add_filter('gutenberg_can_edit_post', '__return_false', 10);

// disable for post types
add_filter('gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', '__return_false', 10);
```

Comment: You can get paid plugins too to avoid the Gutenberge.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular way is to use one of several plugins that remove Gutenberg functionality and restore the classic editor for WordPress versions 5.0.1+; take a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ They have options to selectively use Gutenberg in posts and pages.

You could take the code from either plugin and integrate it into your theme, but a plugin gives you the option to easily disable it. You can also add either plugin as an `mu` must-use plugin so it can't be deactivated by users except by FTP. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I have managed this with one line of code add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false'); the only error in my add filter is I am using return true instead of return false.

Answer (score 2):

1) https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/ (this plugin can help to deactivate gutenberg)

2) https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ (this plugin can help to get back classic editor )

3) Add in below code in your theme funtions.php file.

```
remove_action( 'try_gutenberg_panel', 'wp_try_gutenberg_panel' );
```

OR

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false' );
```

(through coding)